# why python regex is so slow?

Tags: python, regex

After long debugging I found why my application using python regexps is slow. Here is something I find surprising:

```
import datetime
import re

pattern = re.compile('(.*)sol(.*)')

lst = ["ciao mandi "*10000 + "sol " + "ciao mandi "*10000,
       "ciao mandi "*1000 + "sal " + "ciao mandi "*1000]
for s in lst:
    print "string len", len(s)
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    re.findall(pattern,s)
    print "time spent", datetime.datetime.now() - start
    print
```

The output on my machine is:

```
string len 220004
time spent 0:00:00.002844

string len 22004
time spent 0:00:05.339580
```

The first test string is 220K long, matches, and the matching is quite fast. The second test string is 20K long, does not match and it takes 5 seconds to compute!

I knew this report http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html which says that regexp implementation in python, perl, ruby is somewhat non optimal... Is this the reason? I didn't thought it could happen with such a simple expression.

**added**
My original task is to split a string trying different regex in turn. Something like:

```
for regex in ['(.*)sol(.*)', '\emph{([^{}])*)}(.*)', .... ]:
    lst = re.findall(regex, text) 
    if lst:
        assert len(lst) == 1
        assert len(lst[0]) == 2
        return lst[0]
```

This is to explain why I cannot use `split`. I solved my issue by replacing `(.*)sol(.*)` with `(.*?)sol(.*)` as suggested by Martijn.

Probably I should use `match` instead of `findall`... but I don't think this would have solved the issue since the regexp is going to match the entire input and hence findall should stop at first match.

Anyway my question was more about how easy is to fall in this problem for a regexp newbie... I think it is not so simple to understand that `(.*?)sol(.*)` is the solution (and for example `(.*?)sol(.*?)` is not).

Comment: No, the reason is not the implementation. The reason is that the two `.*` are too permissive and cause a catastrophic backtracking. What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: @casimir, the catastrophic backtracking _is_ the implementation problem. Read the article linked by Emanuele.

Comment: @alexis: No, the catastrophic backtracking in this case is due to the pattern conception. You will obtain more or less the same result with other NFA engines.

Comment: Read the article. "The other NFA engines" have the same implementation. A real FSA would not need any backtracking.

Comment: One more note: the problem is not caused by the double `(.*)`. Searching for `(.*)sol` has exactly the same time profile. In fact `(.*)sol` is actually _worse_ if the string contains `sol` and you search with `findall()`, since it triggers a failed backtracking search on the substring that follows `sol`. (The original RE will consume the entire string on success).

Comment: I had the same slowness problem - waited more than 2 minutes, as the string was very long. I installed the package `regex` - works great! got the result immediately for the same string. Downloaded from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Thompson NFA approach changes regular expressions from default greedy to default non-greedy. Normal regular expression engines can do the same; simply change `.*` to `.*?`. You should not use greedy expressions when non-greedy will do.

Someone already built an NFA regular expression parser for Python: https://github.com/xysun/regex

It indeed outperforms the default Python regular expression parser for the pathological cases. *However*, it **under**-performs on *everything else*:

> This regex engine underperforms Python's re module on normal inputs (using Glenn Fowler's test suite -- see below)

Fixing the pathological case at the expense of the typical is probably a good reason not to use the NFA approach as a default engine, not when the pathological case can simply be avoided instead.

Another reason is that certain features (such as back references) are either very hard or impossible to implement using the NFA approach. Also see the [response on the Python Ideas mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2007-April/000407.html).

As such, your test can be made to perform much better if you made at least one of the patterns non-greedy to avoid the catastrophic backtracking:

```
pattern = re.compile('(.*?)sol(.*)')
```

or don't use a regex at all; you could use `str.partition()` to get the prefix and postfix instead:

```
before, sol, after = s.partition('sol')
```

e.g. not all text problems are regular-expression shaped, so put down that hammer and look at the rest of your toolbox!

In addition, you could perhaps look at the alternative `re` module, [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). This module implements some basic checks for pathological cases and avoids them deftly, without having to resort to a Thompson NFA implementation. Quoting [an entry to a Python bug report tracking `regex`](https://bugs.python.org/issue2636#msg90954):

> The internal engine no longer interprets a form of bytecode but instead
>   follows a linked set of nodes, and it can work breadth-wise as well as
>   depth-first, which makes it perform much better when faced with one of
>   those 'pathological' regexes.

This engine can run your pathological case more than 100 thousand times faster:

```
>>> import re, regex
>>> import timeit
>>> p_re = re.compile('(.*)sol(.*)')
>>> p_regex = regex.compile('(.*)sol(.*)')
>>> s = "ciao mandi "*1000 + "sal " + "ciao mandi "*1000
>>> timeit.timeit("p.findall(s)", 'from __main__ import s, p_re as p', number=1)
2.4578459990007104
>>> timeit.timeit("p.findall(s)", 'from __main__ import s, p_regex as p', number=100000)
1.955532732012216
```

Note the numbers; I limited the `re` test to 1 run and it took 2.46 seconds, while the `regex` test runs 100k times in under 2 seconds.

Comment: In my use case I want to split some text in two pieces, but the splitting is achieved by many different regexps (which I concatenate with |) some of them more complicated than this (but not so slow...). So it would be nice to keep this matching in a regexp.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: for *splitting* you'd use `re.split()`, and then you'd not need to use `.*` at all for the part before and after the `sol` text.

Comment: What's wrong with [the upcoming `regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)? That's fast and way faster on most pathological ones. For this example it's more than fast enough. Anyway, I downvoted because I think drawing performance conclusions from comparing a heavily optimized C implementation with a hastily-made pure-Python implementation is about the worst benchmarking I've seen *anyone* do, ever.

Comment: @Veedrac: I had not payed attention to the specifics of that implementation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yet you drew conclusions from it.

Comment: @Veedrac: sure, I had mistakingly assumed that they knew what they were doing. I read the benchmarking results layed out in the README.

Comment: @Veedrac: what is the status of the `regex` module anyway? Is there a plan yet for when to include it in Python stdlib?

Comment: It keeps getting suggested and everyone seems to support it, but it never gets done. [The issue has a good summary of "why"](http://bugs.python.org/issue2636) although that question is best answered as "not enough manpower".

Comment: @MartijnPieters i think I cannot use re.split. Some of the patterns to split my text is like: `r"\emph{([^{}]*)}(.*)"` (maybe I shouldn't call this a "split").

Answer (score 8):

I think this has nothing to do with catastrophic backtracking (or at least my own understanding of it).

The problem is caused by the first `(.*)` in `(.*)sol(.*)`, and the fact that the regex is not anchored anywhere.

`re.findall()`, after failing at index 0, would retry at index 1, 2, etc. until the end of the string.

```
badbadbadbad...bad
^                   Attempt to match (.*)sol(.*) from index 0. Fail
 ^                  Attempt to match (.*)sol(.*) from index 1. Fail
  ^                 Attempt to match (.*)sol(.*) from index 2. Fail (and so on)
```

It effectively has quadratic complexity O(n<sup>2</sup>) where n is the length of the string.

The problem can be resolved by anchoring your pattern, so it fails right away at positions that your pattern has no chance to match. `(.*)sol(.*)` will search for `sol` within a line of text (delimited by line terminator), so if it can't find a match at the start of the line, it won't find any for the rest of the line.

Therefore, you can use:

```
^(.*)sol(.*)
```

with [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) option.

Running this test code (modified from yours):

```
import datetime
import re

pattern = re.compile('^(.*)sol(.*)', re.MULTILINE)

lst = ["ciao mandi "*10000 + "sol " + "ciao mandi "*10000,
       "ciao mandi "*10000 + "sal " + "ciao mandi "*10000]
for s in lst:
    print "string len", len(s)
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    re.findall(pattern,s)
    print "time spent", datetime.datetime.now() - start
    print
```

(Note that both passing and failing are 220004 characters)

Gives the following result:

```
string len 220004
time spent 0:00:00.002000

string len 220004
time spent 0:00:00.005000
```

This demonstrates clearly that both cases now have the same order of magnitude.

Comment: This is interesting... in fact the point is that `re.search` is slow while `re.match` is fast. However I tried to make the same search with `awk` (but I'm not 100% sure I used an equivalent pattern) and seems that for `awk` a search and a match take the same time. Maybe the point is that with NFA approach I can implement a search in linear time where a repeated match would require quadratic time.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: awk doesn't use backtracking engine. That's why it is fast.

Comment: Is this not what pathological backtracking is?

Comment: @Veedrac: This is more of the behavior at the top level (where the engine advance to the next index after all possibilities at the current index have been exhausted). Well technically, you can define it to be "catastrophic backtracking", but it is different from the case (a*)*, where the problem happens due to the engine allowing a*a* expansion. The solution for the 2 cases are different also. But I agree that in the end, any inefficiencies are due to excessive backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=(.*?sol))\1(.*)$
```

You can try this.This reduces backtracking and fails faster.Try your string here.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/22

Comment: What makes you think that it fails faster and backtracks less?

Comment: So you're capturing and immediately backreferencing the captured group, and claiming it fails faster with the additional capture; What gives? Well, this does take longer to succeed, and doesn't really fail faster.

Comment: @Unihedron well i check at regexhero.net ...in failure in a small string it was 132% faster and when success it was 50 % faster.I guess that is a significant improvement

Comment: @Jerry it takes less number of steps as well

Comment: You're using non-greedy matching, which is faster than greedy backtracking search as Martijn pointed out. Was this actually faster than the *non-greedy* version of the OP's regexp?

Comment: @alexis tried that too.it took less number of steps.

Comment: @vks You were already told in your own question that the number of steps is not the final factor for speed. The only that is making this slightly faster than the OP's regex are the anchors. Use anchors on the OP's regex and that one is much slower than OP's current regex.

Comment: @Jerry I have benchmarked it at regexhero....no, of steps was just an indication.....